# How to use display/view only Twproject Gantt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gantt-chart

I am trying to using [Twproject Gantt](https://gantt.twproject.com/applications/gantt/distrib/gantt.jsp). I don't form [GitHub](https://github.com/robicch/jQueryGantt).
But, I just want to use **display/view** only. I don't need add or edit or others function.
I already try to configure`"canWrite":false`.It does not work. How to configure view only mode in `Twproject Gantt`?

Answer (score 0):

Configure view only mode : (i am using this settings)

First, you need to remove all save and delete button to prevent client mistaken it. (search this one for this issue) :

> class="**template**" type="GANTBUTTONS"

then when DB load , try to set the json there like this one :

```
{
    "tasks":[],
    "selectedRow":0, 
    "canWrite":false, //is a must
    "canWriteOnParent":false, //is a must
    "roles":[],  //optional
    "resources":[] //optional
}
```

May this answer your question.

Moreover, you can browse this one [Documentation](https://roberto.open-lab.com/2012/08/24/jquery-gantt-editor/)
or [github jQueryGantt](https://github.com/robicch/jQueryGantt)